# centos6.4 fetchmail not downloading mail more than 5MB?

Tags: linux, centos, email, fetchmail

i just configured fetchmail in CentOS 6.4.

by the help of [this tutorial](http://www.gaztronics.net/scripts/fetchmail.php)

everything is working mail is downloading well.

But it's not downloading mails with attachments more than 5MB(approx.).

what should i do that it can download mail max 25MB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the configured limit set by `--limit` or `-l` or the limits set in the configuration file using the directive `limit`.

See `man fetchmail`, search for `limit` and https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fetchmail&manpath=SuSE+Linux/i386+11.3 for more details.